# ipad, Need help with a memory leak

Tags: c, ipad, memory-leaks

I have this code:

```
void getStringWithTag(char* pFile, long sizeSound, char* tag, char* ret, float* currentPos){
char* tagCopy;
tagCopy = (char*)malloc(256 * sizeof(char));
int totalLen = 0;
int tempLen = 0;
memset(tagCopy, 0, 256);
memset(ret, 0, 128);
pFile += ((int)*currentPos);
while (totalLen+(*currentPos) < sizeSound) {
    if (*pFile == '<') {
        pFile += 5;
        totalLen += 5;
        while(*pFile != '>'){
            *tagCopy = *pFile;
            tagCopy++;
            pFile++;
            totalLen++;
            tempLen++;
        }
        tagCopy -= tempLen;
        tempLen = 0;
        if (strcmp(tagCopy, tag) == 0) {
            pFile++;
            totalLen++;
            while (*pFile != '<') {
                *ret = *pFile;
                ret++;
                pFile++;
                totalLen++;
                tempLen++;
            }
            ret -= tempLen;
            *currentPos += totalLen;
            tagCopy = NULL;
            free(tagCopy);
            return;
        }else{
            memset(tagCopy, 0, 256);
        }
    }
    pFile++;
    totalLen++;
}
tagCopy = NULL;
free(tagCopy);
*currentPos = sizeSound;
ret = NULL;
}
```

That apparently gives me a memory leak with "tagCopy".
Can anyone tell me why? I thought I had this down pretty good but this is the only place where I get a memory leak.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You modify `tagCopy` a few times in that routine, and then you try to free it later.  Probably dangerous.  You're also setting `tagCopy` to `NULL` before calling `free()`, so every time you try to free `NULL` rather than the actual memory you allocated.

Comment: hmm, do you have any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: Well said.  It would be better to use array syntax (`tagCopy[i]`) or an alias pointer.  Modifying `tagCopy` makes it harder to analyze.

Comment: @funckymonk, Matthew has good suggestions.  I would say 1) don't bother setting it to `NULL` ever, and 2) avoid ever modifying it in the routine (or save a copy of the original pointer for freeing later if you prefer).

Comment: @Carl Norum - Its a good practice to set a pointer to NULL after free. Isnt it?

Comment: @Praveen, maybe if it were a global.  In this case there is absolutely no reason to do so.

Comment: ... in particular not *before* freeing it.

Comment: Thank you everybody for the help!
I got it to work leak free.
I took Matthews suggestions and made a tagCopy[256] and used that instead.